# Group extensions rational matrices by infinite cyclic squared

Tags: group-theory, group-extensions

Are there any nontrivial group extensions : 
$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow G \rightarrow Gl_2(\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow 0 $ ? Any referall to literature is greatly welcomed. Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: This is a strange question. I don't think there are any nontrivial extensions of ${\mathbb Z}^2$ by ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Q})$, so this seems to be equivalent to asking about extensions of ${\mathbb Z}^2$ by $({\mathbb Q} \setminus \{0\},\times)$, which is a direct product of $\langle -1 \rangle \times ({\mathbb Q}_{\ge 0},\times)$. So there is at least one nontrivial extensions coming from the direct factor $\langle -1 \rangle$, which could square into an element of ${\mathbb Z}^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why do you say this about $SL_2(Q)$?

Comment: @YCor I don't believe there is any nontrivial action of ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Q})$ on ${\mathbb Z}^2$, so this would have to be a central extension. For some reason I thought that the Schur Multiplier of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Q})$ was trivial but perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: @DerekHolt This Schur multiplier is nontrivial. We can consider the inverse image of $SL_2(\mathbf{Q})$ in the universal covering of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$. Since it is torsion-free, it shows that the Schur multiplier is nontrivial (but maybe does not provide extensions by $\mathbf{Z}$).

Comment: $H_2(SL_2(k))$ is equal to second Milnor-Witt K-theory of a field in case $k$ is infinite and it's apparently nonzero for rationals.